# Loading Twitch Player fails with Twitch not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am geting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Twitch is not defined` when I am trying to run the html code below:

```
<div class="custom-box well" id="templateHolder">
    <script src="https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
    <div id="testDivId"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var options = {width:600,height:400,channel:"cookingForNoobs"};
        var player = new Twitch.Player("testDivId", options);
        player.setVolume(0.5);
    </script>
</div>
```

When I run it in jsfiddle it works and does not complain about not finding `Twitch` . However, as part of my page it does. The page correctly loads except for this div. Also using `<iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=cookingfornoobs&amp;muted=true" width="100%" height="800px"></iframe>` will work. I am not sure if there is something blocking the call for loading the Twitch player.

Is there something I can check for to make sure its being handled correctly?

As a note it occurs in Chrome as well as Firefox and I am able to see player.twitch.tv js/embed v1.js file under the sources tab.

Comment: https://www.giantbomb.com/forums/bug-reporting-33/chrome-41-0-2272-76-not-loading-embeded-twitch-pla-1767513/

Comment: I checked that, unfortunately its not a chrome issue, and I am not encountering network errors only the Twitch not defined error. Also I see the twitch v1.js in the sources tab.

Comment: @Niru. When new Twitch.Player is interpretted your library might still be loading. Try wrapping your second script with document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" or window.onload.

Comment: I added <script src="https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js" onload="loadPlayer()"></script> and defined it as the script above. It no longer errors out but does not render the player either.

Comment: @karthick What you mentioned worked. The solution ended up being that I added a loadPlayer() function which only displayed once the twitch script finished loading. Please move your comment to the answers so I can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When new Twitch.Player is interpretted your library might still be loading.

Try wrapping the twitch initialization within "DOMContentLoaded" or in `window.onload = function(){}` if you are using jquery then within `$(document).ready(){}`